# Getting Error while using group_by and summarize in sparkdataframe inside data bricks

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have been trying to summarise the data. While using the same code inside Rstuido, it works fine, but when using inside data bricks, if I use it, it throws me an error.

```
veganWidebySoilRanch <- allTransitionVegdataLongWithSoil %>% 
group_by(Farm,SoilName,SoilTexture, Species) %>% 
summarize(Total = n())
```

This is the error I am getting.:

**The error occurred in group 1: Triangle_ID = "T22001", Species = " ".
Caused by error:
! unable to find an inherited method for function ‘n’ for signature ‘"missing"’
Error in `summarise()`|**

I tried to use ```dplyr::group_by``, but it is not working. Could anyone suggest?

Comment: You have a missing value in Species. Probably where Triangle_ID = T22001.

Comment: I removed it but still not working.  But with some missing values, the same command worked in Rstuido.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the complete code for a minimal, reproducible example. Probably some of your data too.

Comment: dput(head(vegatation[, c(1, 3)]))

structure(list(Triangle_ID = c("T22001", "T22002", "T220003", "T20004", "T20005", "T20006"), 
    Species= c ("NA", " AMBR", "AMBO" , "SMBO", "SCSC", "sylv")), .Names = c("Triangle_ID", 
"Species"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in databricks I frequently find I need to explicitly put the package name in front of the function. In this case, the offending function is n(). Try:

```
veganWidebySoilRanch <- allTransitionVegdataLongWithSoil %>% 
dplyr::group_by(Farm,SoilName,SoilTexture, Species) %>% 
dplyr::summarize(Total = dplyr::n())
```